# How to write list of objects to ConfigMap?

Tags: spring, kubernetes, configmap

I have `yaml` with lines:

```
accounts:
  service:
    - id: account1
      username: foo
      password: bar
    - id: account2
      username: foo1
      password: bar1
```

It's default values for my app. But I want to change it in `ConfigMap`. I do something like that:

```
accounts.service[0].id: id0
accounts.service[0].username: username0
accounts.service[0].password: password0

accounts.service[1].id: id1
accounts.service[1].username: username1
accounts.service[1].password: password1

accounts.service[2].id: id2
accounts.service[2].username: username2
accounts.service[2].password: password2
```

It doesn't work. How can I do it correctly? The list of objects can be with random size.

And, of course, password I'd like to storage in secrets.

Comment: A ConfigMap stores a mapping of string keys to string values; it can't store more structured data without having is somehow encoded to a string.  In the context of a Spring Java application, either the YAML or Java properties file you show could be stored in a single ConfigMap key.  What have you tried so far, and what problems are you running into?  Are you having trouble creating the ConfigMap, mounting it into your application, something else?

Answer (score 1):

If your app, works and can read the yaml as in your example you can create a configMap from your yaml file like so:

kubectl create configmap myconfigmap  --from-file=myfile.yaml --dry-run=client -o yaml > output-configmap-file.yaml

where myfile.yaml is your yaml file.

this will create locally the output-configmap-file.yaml in the right format for Kubernetes.
You can edit this, add namespaces, and what evver you need
kubectl apply -f output-configmap-file.yaml, will create your configmap in the cluster.

Inside your deployment of the app, create a volume with that configMap and mount it inside your container specs.
Like so:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mydeployment
  namespace: mynamespace
  labels:
    app: api
spec:

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          volumeMounts:
            - name: myyaml
              mountPath: /path/to-your-yaml/myyaml.yaml
              subPath: myyaml.yaml
          image: myimage
.........

........
      volumes:
        - name: myyaml
          configMap:
            name: myconfigMap
```

This will take the configMap and mount it as your yaml file inside the container.
So you don't even need to put the file in your image.

Hint: Passwords don't belong inside the configMap. Secrets are better place.

Comment: But I'd like to override few parameters in `ConfigMap`, not all.